# Linq left join and groug by and check null values

Tags: linq

I am very new to linq, i am trying to convert SQL into Linq

SQL statement:

```sql
select cat_name, cat_id, count(pro_fk_cat_id) as count 
from tbl_category c 
    left join tbl_product p on c.cat_id = p.pro_fk_cat_id 
group by
    cat_name, 
    cat_id,
    pro_fk_cat_id
```

This is the result i am looking for in linq

```
 category name  categoryID   count (number of products)
   Movies         2           65
   PS4 Games      3           26
   Printers       8           0
   Head phones    9           0
   Speakers       10          0
```

i have tried that, it worked, but it has turned "0" into "1". i mean, where no product exist in a category it should say "0" instead it says "1"

thanks in advance

What I have tried:

```cs
var results = 
    from procat in this.objDB.tbl_category
    join product in this.objDB.tbl_Product on procat.cat_id 
    equals product.pro_fk_cat_id  into productdetail
    from productdetaildata in productdetail.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new CategoryModel
    {
        cat_name = procat.cat_name,
        cat_id = procat.cat_id,
        related_count = productdetaildata.pro_fk_cat_id
    };


IEnumerable<CategoryModel> CategoryList = 
    results.GroupBy(x => x.cat_id, (key, _data) => new CategoryModel
    {
        cat_name = _data.Select(x => x.cat_name).FirstOrDefault(),
        cat_id = _data.Select(x => x.cat_id).FirstOrDefault(),
        related_count = _data.Count()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

GroupBy in query syntax almost similar. `Count` probably should be emulated by `Sum`. It's support depends on EF Core version.

```cs
var results = 
    from procat in this.objDB.tbl_category
    join product in this.objDB.tbl_Product on procat.cat_id 
    equals product.pro_fk_cat_id  into productdetail
    from productdetaildata in productdetail.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group productdetaildata by new { procat.cat_name, procat.cat_id } into g
    select new CategoryModel
    {
        cat_name = g.Key.cat_name,
        cat_id = g.Key.cat_id,
        related_count = g.Sum(x => (int?)x.pro_fk_cat_id == null ? 0 : 1) 
    };
```